# Mongo aggregate query extremely slow

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

So, I'm running what I feel ought to be a relatively simple query. Essentially I'm just summing the length of all the lists in a particular field.

I have ~250k documents in the database, with each document being about 200kb. The query is shown below, a very basic aggregate, but it currently takes ~30min to run. Is there anything I could do to speed this up? It feels silly to me that summing 250k elements would take half an hour.

```
db.user_data.aggregate([{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: {$size: "$text"}}}}])
```

I'm running on an m3.large ec2 instance running 14.04 for specs.

Comment: What MongoDB version and how large are the arrays on average per document? Arrays with over 500 elements is not a great idea. If you can then try and use a latest 2.6.x release if your not able to upgrade to 3.0.x.

Comment: Using 2.6.8. Arrays are ~400-500 elements on average, ranging from 0 to ~800

Comment: Well there you go. Performance is noted to drop off considerably with arrays beyond 500 elements. I would suggest to try to maintain the "size" as an element in your document and also re-think the general architecture  if you are growing arrays to those sort of sizes. You could trial the same operation as a mapReduce statement,but I'm not thinking it likely there would be an improvement, and it's probably worse.

Comment: @NeilLunn Could you send me a reference on that performance drop? I know mongo doesn't handle arrays elegantly, but they aren't growing, which I thought was the main issue. These documents are created once more or less and I've avoided the main problems detailed here: http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays. I suppose I could store the size, but it not straightforward or intuitive to change the architecture otherwise.

Comment: Well you can output your aggregation into new collection and use that collection for quering the data. Here is a link for the $out setting http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: @sirfilip, the aggregation is a single number and I have to run it many times on varying data.

Comment: Yup sorry about that mate, well maybe you can try different approach then aggregating not sure how else i could be of help but in general i am using aggregation for something like building reports and i am keeping the results of the aggregation inside output collection. In this case i dont think that it can help.

Answer (score -1):

You might try using `$unwind`, to see if it goes any faster that way:

```
db.user_data.aggregate([{$project:{text:1, _id:0}}, {$unwind:"$text"},
    {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

Comment: Umm. **`$size`** is an operator that works on arrays. And your solution to "speed up" is to duplicate documents up to 800 times and then use $sum to obtain the count? So do you expect people to find this useful? Or do you think they just might vote for "not useful"?

Comment: The `$project` at the beginning strips all the other fields from the documents before the unwind, so there's no duplication being done.

Comment: Sorry about the `$size` being left in there, I've now corrected the answer.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all `$size` **is** the correct thing to use. Project is not "reducing" any more than what is already being done (See [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/)). So the point was that both your `$project` and the `$unwind` come at a greater cost. So this cannot possiblly "improve performance", which is what the question was asking. And why no-one else attempted to answer. Read the comments. The array size is the problem here.

Comment: What can I say, but that it was not obvious to me whether using $unwind would have as much of a performance issue as using $size, and it seemed like a simple enough thing for the OP to test, in his environment against his data.